# How do I update workspace names without quitting icewm?

Tags: workspace, icewm

I'm using icewm on Arch Linux. Sometimes I want to add another workspace, or rename them. I edit ~/.icewm/preferences, then in an xterm do 'icewm --restart'.   This usually picks up changes in the preferences file, and will add new workspaces with the proper names when the number of them increases, but does not update the workspace names for existing workspaces. They keep their previous names.

Simple example to illustrate what I mean:

preferences, before edit:

```
WorkspaceNames="A","B","C"
```

after editing:

```
WorkspaceNames="A","Y","Z","N"
```

After saving and restarting, I find the taskbar shows four workspaces labelled A, B, C, N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IceWM first looks to the root window for workspace names. If found then those are preferred over your preferences.

You can see this by doing:

```
xprop -root _NET_DESKTOP_NAMES
```

These are destroyed when you logout. On login your preferences will be read.

You could also use the commands:

```
  icesh setWorkspaceNames A Y Z N

  icesh restart
```

Comment: Verified, those commands work. Life is good.